# SQL Server - CTE Recursive SUM Value From Different Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with data stored hierarchically in a table named **CsOrganization** like in the following table.

```
Table Name : CsOrganization
OrgId   OrgParentId    OrgName
1       NULL           X COMPANY
2       1              Administrator
3       2              Adm 1
4       2              Adm 2
5       3              Adm 1_1
```

And then there's a  table named **EmHisOrganization** which related to **CsOrganization** table like in the following table.

```
Table Name : EmHisOrganization
EmpId   OrgId    
1       2          
2       2        
3       3       
4       4        
5       5
```

Each employee will have overtime data based on the organization they have, and they stored in **EmOvertime** table.

```
Table Name : EmOvertime
EmpId   TotalOtReal    
1       1.00          
2       2.00        
3       3.00       
4       2.00        
5       1.00
```

**The problem is I need to get the sum of TotalHours based on each Organization. The sum of TotalHours must also sum all of its child's TotalHours data.** So far, I managed to figure out their parent and child, but I can't figure out how to get TotalHours data from a different table and make a sum of it. As far as I know, I need to join those tables to get TotalHours, but unfortunately CTE Recursive doesn't allow to use OUTER JOIN in the syntax. Here's the output I want based on the examples above:

```
Desired Output
OrgId      OrgName       TotalHours    
1          X COMPANY     9.00
2          Administrator 9.00
3          Adm 1         4.00 
4          Adm 2         2.00
5          Adm 1_1       1.00
```

Notice that TotalHours of Adm 1 is from the sum Employee with ID 3 which has a value of 3.00 in TotalHours column and Employee with ID 5 which has a value of 1.00 in TotalHours column, which resulted 4.00 in the desired table. The same goes when OrgId with ID 1 and 2 got the value of 9.00 in TotalHours.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edited On 09/05/2016, 12.02**, added relationship of the tables and my query attempts.

Here's the look of the relationship: [Table Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m59ds.png).

My Query attempts (these resulted 0.00 on each Organization, but the anchor query is showing the right value, if the where clause is deprecated):

```
With OrgTree (OrgId, OrgName, TotalHours) AS
(
SELECT      orgId, orgN, SUM(eReal) AS TotalHours
FROM        (SELECT OrgId AS orgId, OrgName AS orgN, CASE WHEN x.TotalOtReal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE x.TotalOtReal END AS eReal
FROM        (SELECT f.OrgId, f.OrgName, o.TotalOtReal
FROM        dbo.CsOrganization AS f LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT     OrgId, SUM(TotalOtReal) AS TotalOtReal
FROM        (SELECT a.EmpId, a.OrgId, b.TotalOtReal
FROM        dbo.EmHisOrganization AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT     EmpId, SUM(TotalOtReal) AS TotalOtReal
FROM        dbo.EmOvertime AS a
GROUP BY EmpId) AS b ON a.EmpId = b.EmpId) AS a_1
GROUP BY OrgId) AS o ON f.OrgId = o.OrgId
) AS x WHERE OrgId = 1) AS xx
GROUP BY orgId, orgN

UNION ALL
SELECT a.OrgId, a.OrgName, TotalHours FROM dbo.CsOrganization a
INNER JOIN OrgTree o ON a.OrgParentId = o.OrgId
)
SELECT a.OrgId, a.OrgName, SUM(a.TotalHours) AS TotalHours FROM OrgTree a
GROUP BY a.OrgId, a.OrgName
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the tag for the relevant rdbms, and also your attempts of solving the problem.

Comment: I've edited my question above, please take a look.

Comment: But still we don't know that database you are working with. cte's are supported on many platforms. is it sql server, oracle, postgre, something else?

Comment: Oh, it's SQL Server we're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @CsOrganization TABLE (OrgId int, OrgParentId int, OrgName nvarchar(50));
INSERT INTO @CsOrganization (OrgId, OrgParentId, OrgName) VALUES
(1, NULL, 'X COMPANY'),
(2, 1   , 'Administrator'),
(3, 2   , 'Adm 1'),
(4, 2   , 'Adm 2'),
(5, 3   , 'Adm 1_1');

DECLARE @EmHisOrganization TABLE (EmpId int, OrgId int);
INSERT INTO @EmHisOrganization (EmpId, OrgId) VALUES
(1, 2),
(2, 2),
(3, 3),
(4, 4),
(5, 5);

DECLARE @EmOvertime TABLE (EmpId int, TotalOtReal float);
INSERT INTO @EmOvertime (EmpId, TotalOtReal) VALUES
(1, 1.00),
(2, 2.00),
(3, 3.00),
(4, 2.00),
(5, 1.00);
```

**Query**

- `CTE_OrgHours` calculates the simple sum of overtime hours for all employees of each organisation.
- `CTE_Recursive` is the recursive CTE that traverses the hierarchy of organisations.
- Final `SELECT` groups the traversed tree to sum hours for each node (organisation) of the tree.

Run this query step-by-step, CTE-by-CTE and examine intermediate results to get a better understanding of how it works.

```
WITH
CTE_OrgHours
AS
(
    SELECT
        Org.OrgId
        ,Org.OrgParentId
        ,Org.OrgName
        ,ISNULL(SUM(Overtime.TotalOtReal), 0) AS SumHours
    FROM
        @CsOrganization AS Org
        LEFT JOIN @EmHisOrganization AS Emp ON Emp.OrgId = Org.OrgID
        LEFT JOIN @EmOvertime AS Overtime ON Overtime.EmpId = Emp.EmpId
    GROUP BY
        Org.OrgId
        ,Org.OrgParentId
        ,Org.OrgName
)
,CTE_Recursive
AS
(
    SELECT
         CTE_OrgHours.OrgId
        ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgParentId
        ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgName
        ,CTE_OrgHours.SumHours
        ,1 AS Lvl
        ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgId AS StartOrgId
        ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgName AS StartOrgName
    FROM CTE_OrgHours

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
         CTE_OrgHours.OrgId
        ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgParentId
        ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgName
        ,CTE_OrgHours.SumHours
        ,CTE_Recursive.Lvl + 1 AS Lvl
        ,CTE_Recursive.StartOrgId
        ,CTE_Recursive.StartOrgName
    FROM
        CTE_OrgHours
        INNER JOIN CTE_Recursive ON CTE_Recursive.OrgId = CTE_OrgHours.OrgParentId
)
SELECT
    StartOrgId
    ,StartOrgName
    ,SUM(SumHours) AS TotalHours
FROM CTE_Recursive
GROUP BY
    StartOrgId
    ,StartOrgName
ORDER BY StartOrgId;
```

**Result**

```
+------------+---------------+------------+
| StartOrgId | StartOrgName  | TotalHours |
+------------+---------------+------------+
|          1 | X COMPANY     |          9 |
|          2 | Administrator |          9 |
|          3 | Adm 1         |          4 |
|          4 | Adm 2         |          2 |
|          5 | Adm 1_1       |          1 |
+------------+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: Wow, it worked out nicely! Thank you very much! Marked this as an answer!

Comment: But wait, suppose the EmOvertime table had another column, say "AttdDate", which means many employee with the same ID can be inserted but with different date, it would be resulted duplicate child's data. How to avoid this?

Comment: @Reynaldi, it depends on what result you need. Right now the query sums all rows (hours) for each organisation. If you need something different, you'd better ask another question and explain in detail what you need and how result of this query differs from what you expect. Show some sample data with dates and what result you expect, as you did with this question.

Comment: I've posted another question. Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37128068/sql-server-cte-recursive-looping-in-childs-data

Answer (score 0):

What you think about Nestet Sets patern ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model))?

```
OrgId   LeftIndex RightIndex    OrgName
1       1         10            X COMPANY
2       2         9             Administrator
3       3         6             Adm 1
4       7         8             Adm 2
5       4         5             Adm 1_1

SELECT O.OrgId, (SELECT Sum(EO.TotalHours)
   FROM CsOrganization CO
   INNER JOIN EmHisOrganization AS EHO ON CO.OrgId=EHO.OrgID
   INNER JOIN EmOvertime AS EO ON EHO.EmpId=EO.EmpId
   WHERE CO.LeftInde>=O.LeftIndex AND CO.RightIndex<=O.RightIndex) AS TotalHours
FROM CsOrganization O
```

Comment: How do I know the value of LeftIndex and RightIndex? Do I have to add another two columns in CsOrganization table?

Comment: Yes, you mast add two columns instead OrgParentId column.There is another waywithout new columns. You must create a function to calculate the sum.

Comment: You can not use WITH expression in subquery, therefore you must use function