# SQL Server - CTE Recursive, Looping in Child's Data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This question continues from the previous solved question (much thanks to Vladimir Baranov), which can be accessed here: [SQL Server - CTE Recursive SUM Value From Different Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107678/sql-server-cte-recursive-sum-value-from-different-table).

The data structures are pretty much the same as before, except there's another column named 'AttdDate' in **EmOvertime** to indicate employee's attendance date. Here's an example of data in **EmOvertime** table.

```
Table Name : EmOvertime
EmpId    AttdDate     TotalOtReal    
2        2016-05-09   2.00          
2        2016-05-10   2.00        
2        2016-05-11   2.00       
2        2016-05-12   2.00        
3        2016-05-12   3.00
```

The data from **CsOrganization** and **EmHisOrganization** are the same as the previous question. Suppose I want to show all organization data with its TotalHours value on 12-May-2016, the query would be like this:

```
WITH
CTE_OrgHours
AS
(
SELECT
    Org.OrgId
    ,Org.OrgParentId
    ,Org.OrgName
    ,ISNULL(Overtime.TotalOtReal, 0) AS SumHours
    ,Overtime.AttdDate
FROM
    CsOrganization AS Org
    LEFT JOIN EmHisOrganization AS Emp ON Emp.OrgId = Org.OrgID
    LEFT JOIN EmOvertime AS Overtime ON Overtime.EmpId = Emp.EmpId
GROUP BY
    Org.OrgId
    ,Org.OrgParentId
    ,Org.OrgName
    ,Overtime.TotalOtReal
    ,Overtime.AttdDate
)
,CTE_Recursive
AS
(
SELECT
     CTE_OrgHours.OrgId
    ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgParentId
    ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgName
    ,CTE_OrgHours.SumHours
    ,CTE_OrgHours.AttdDate
    ,1 AS Lvl
    ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgId AS StartOrgId
    ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgName AS StartOrgName
FROM CTE_OrgHours

UNION ALL

SELECT
     CTE_OrgHours.OrgId
    ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgParentId
    ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgName
    ,CTE_OrgHours.SumHours
    ,CTE_OrgHours.AttdDate
    ,CTE_Recursive.Lvl + 1 AS Lvl
    ,CTE_Recursive.StartOrgId
    ,CTE_Recursive.StartOrgName
FROM
    CTE_OrgHours
    INNER JOIN CTE_Recursive ON CTE_Recursive.OrgId = CTE_OrgHours.OrgParentId
)
SELECT
    StartOrgId
    ,StartOrgName
    ,SUM(SumHours) AS TotalHours
FROM CTE_Recursive
WHERE AttdDate = '2016-05-12'
GROUP BY
    StartOrgId
    ,StartOrgName
ORDER BY StartOrgId
```

But the result of the query is showing like this:

```
OrgId      OrgName       TotalHours    
1          X COMPANY     14.00
2          Administrator 14.00
3          Adm 1         12.00 
4          Adm 2         0.00
5          Adm 1_1       0.00
```

While the correct one should be like this:

```
Desired Output
OrgId      OrgName       TotalHours    
1          X COMPANY     5.00
2          Administrator 5.00
3          Adm 1         3.00 
4          Adm 2         0.00
5          Adm 1_1       0.00
```

It seems that the child's data was looped as the quantity of its parent's data in **EmOvertime**, which has 4 same IDs. Hence, the value 12.00 is shown. How to fix this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple, if you are interested in one specific date.

It looks like you need to move the `WHERE` filter  into the earlier part of the query. Into the `CTE_OrgHours`. `CTE_OrgHours` should return one row per organisation with the sum of the relevant hours. All filtering should happen in this query. Recursive part later expects to have one row per organisation in `CTE_OrgHours`.

```
WITH
CTE_OrgHours
AS
(
    SELECT
        Org.OrgId
        ,Org.OrgParentId
        ,Org.OrgName
        ,ISNULL(SUM(Overtime.TotalOtReal), 0) AS SumHours
    FROM
        CsOrganization AS Org
        LEFT JOIN EmHisOrganization AS Emp ON Emp.OrgId = Org.OrgID
        LEFT JOIN EmOvertime AS Overtime
            ON  Overtime.EmpId = Emp.EmpId
            AND Overtime.AttdDate = '2016-05-12'
    GROUP BY
        Org.OrgId
        ,Org.OrgParentId
        ,Org.OrgName
)
,CTE_Recursive
AS
(
    SELECT
         CTE_OrgHours.OrgId
        ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgParentId
        ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgName
        ,CTE_OrgHours.SumHours
        ,1 AS Lvl
        ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgId AS StartOrgId
        ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgName AS StartOrgName
    FROM CTE_OrgHours

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
         CTE_OrgHours.OrgId
        ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgParentId
        ,CTE_OrgHours.OrgName
        ,CTE_OrgHours.SumHours
        ,CTE_Recursive.Lvl + 1 AS Lvl
        ,CTE_Recursive.StartOrgId
        ,CTE_Recursive.StartOrgName
    FROM
        CTE_OrgHours
        INNER JOIN CTE_Recursive ON CTE_Recursive.OrgId = CTE_OrgHours.OrgParentId
)
SELECT
    StartOrgId
    ,StartOrgName
    ,SUM(SumHours) AS TotalHours
FROM CTE_Recursive
GROUP BY
    StartOrgId
    ,StartOrgName
ORDER BY StartOrgId;
```

Comment: My previous attempt was indeed trying to move the WHERE clause from the final SELECT into the CTE_OrgHours, it didn't work out. But then I didn't realized that only adding "AND Overtime.AttdDate = '2016-05-12'" in the ON clause does its job. Thanks again, you're really helped me out. Marked this as an answer!